# Передача ArrayList<String> в другую активити с помощью интерфейса Parcelable

Tags: java, android

Создан класс для передачи через `Intent`:

```
public class Event implements Parcelable{

    private long mID;
    private long mParent;
    private String mThingName;
    private String mDescription;
    private List<String> mFotos;
    private String mDate;
    private int mIsBox;
    private String mPath;

    public Event(long id, long parent, String thingName, String description, ArrayList<String> fotos, String date, int isBox, String path){
        mID = id;
        mParent = parent;
        mThingName = thingName;
        mDescription = description;
        mFotos = fotos;
        mDate = date;
        mIsBox = isBox;
        mPath = path;
    }
    public Event(Parcel in)
    {
        mID = in.readLong();
        mParent = in.readLong();
        mThingName = in.readString();
        mDescription = in.readString();
        in.readStringList(mFotos);
        mDate = in.readString();
        mIsBox = in.readInt();
        mPath = in.readString();
    }



    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(mID);
        dest.writeLong(mParent);
        dest.writeString(mThingName);
        dest.writeString(mDescription);
        dest.writeStringList(mFotos);
        dest.writeString(mDate);
        dest.writeInt(mIsBox);
        dest.writeString(mPath);
    }

    public static final Creator<Event> CREATOR = new Creator<Event>() {
        @Override
        public Event createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Event(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Event[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Event[size];
        }
    };

    public long getID() {
        return mID;
    }

    public long getParent() {
        return mParent;
    }

    public void setParent(long parent) {
        this.mParent = parent;
    }

    public String getThingName() {
        return mThingName;
    }

    public void setThingName(String thingName) {
        this.mThingName = thingName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return mDescription;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.mDescription = description;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFotos() {
        return (ArrayList<String>) mFotos;
    }

    public void setFoto(ArrayList<String> fotos) {
        this.mFotos = fotos;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return mDate;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.mDate = date;
    }

    public int getIsBox() {
        return mIsBox;
    }

    public void setIsBox(int isBox) {
        this.mIsBox = isBox;
    }

    public String getPath(){
        return mPath;
    }
}
```

раньше не было переменной `mFotos`, и все передавалось нормально, а сейчас вылетает программа, при переходе на другую активность. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: И какая ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сразу извиняюсь, что не ответил сразу. На логи мне надо было сразу посмотреть. Выдавало ошибку IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'. Так что проблема была совершенно в другом месте. А именно, как раз при переходе на новую активити, вызывался метод setDate у объекта класса Event. P.S. Всем большее спасибо кто пытался помочь. 
вот код:

```html
Date dateNow = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        event.setDate((new SimpleDateFormat(DB.DATE_FORMAT)).format(dateNow));
```

DATA_FORMAT была равна YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS поменял на yyyy-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS и все заработало

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю проблема, может быть в том что mFotos не инициализируеться через конструктор Event(Parcel in) и он может быть null. Можете скинуть ошибку, которая вылетает.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300608/how-to-pass-a-parcelable-object-that-contains-a-list-of-objects#comment31490561_6300744):

```
mFotos = new ArrayList<String>();
in.readList(mFotos, String.class.getClassLoader()); //или Event.class.getClassLoader()
```