# Подскажите как передать данные через Intent?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MarkerList{

    public MarkerList(int capacity) {
        super(capacity);
    }

    public MarkerList() {
    }

    public MarkerList(Collection collection) {
        super(collection);
    }

    ArrayList<String> lat=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> lng=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> type_2=new ArrayList<>();//Type_2

    public int getSize(){
        return name.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(ArrayList<String> lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(ArrayList<String> lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(ArrayList<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getType_2() {
        return type_2;
    }

    public void setType_2(ArrayList<String> type_2) {
        this.type_2 = type_2;
    }
}
```

У меня есть такой класс. Я не могу передавать через PutExtras. Подскажите как передать мой класс?

Comment: передайте его, как `Parcelable`

Comment: @metalurgus, А можно сделать этот класс static? чтобы не передавать. А то муторно как то через Parcelable. Прям низкоуровневое программирование какое то. На дворе 2016

Comment: Боюсь Java развивается не слишком активно, а появился этот язык в далеком 95м году, так что взывать к 2016 году бесполезно( С другой стороны есть например библиотека [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto) и [плагин к ней делающий класс Parcelable](https://github.com/frankiesardo/auto-parcel). A static класс вас не спасёт при процедуре восстановления состояния после полного завершения приложения.

Comment: Если вас не волнует скорость (которая через Parcelable будет наиболее высокой), можете сериализовать через Serializable, при этом ничего писать дополнительно не надо, либо сделать через сериализацию в json, например Gson'ом...

Comment: Ясно. тобишь в любом случае через intent передавать придеться...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо у вашего класса реализовать интерфейс `Parcelable`. Вот примерный класс, со списком методов и их реализацией - отредактируйте его под ваш класс по аналогии:

```
public class Model implements Parcelable {
    private String title;
    private String text;

    /**
     * Parcel implementation
     */
    private Model(Parcel in) {
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.text = in.readString();
    }

    /**
     * Parcel implementation
     */
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Parcel implementation
     */
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(text);
    }

    /**
     * Parcel implementation
     */
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Model> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Model>() {
        @Override
        public Model createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Model(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Model[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Model[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Важные моменты:

1. Читать поля класса в методе-конструкторе (`private Model(Parcel in)`) надо в том же порядке, в коем они записаны в методе `writeToParcel`
2. Читать строковые списки надо [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523083/17609): `in.readList(mFotos, String.class.getClassLoader());`
3. Как читать/записывать вложенные объекты, реализующие `Parcelable` написано тут: [Записать Parcelable в Parcelable](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/524040/17609)

После этого передавать объект в Bundle Intent-a можно так:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable(someParcelableObject);
```

Answer (score 4):

Есть такая замечательная страничка на котрой можно без проблем сделать Parcelable: http://www.parcelabler.com/

Вот ваш Parcelable класс:

```
public class MarkerList implements Parcelable {

public MarkerList(int capacity) {
    super(capacity);
}

public MarkerList() {
}

public MarkerList(Collection collection) {
    super(collection);
}

ArrayList<String> lat=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> lng=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> type_2=new ArrayList<>();//Type_2

public int getSize(){
    return name.size();
}

public ArrayList<String> getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(ArrayList<String> lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public ArrayList<String> getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(ArrayList<String> lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}

public ArrayList<String> getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(ArrayList<String> name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ArrayList<String> getType_2() {
    return type_2;
}

public void setType_2(ArrayList<String> type_2) {
    this.type_2 = type_2;
}

protected MarkerList(Parcel in) {
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        lat = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.readList(lat, String.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        lat = null;
    }
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        lng = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.readList(lng, String.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        lng = null;
    }
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        name = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.readList(name, String.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        name = null;
    }
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        type_2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        in.readList(type_2, String.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        type_2 = null;
    }
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    if (lat == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(lat);
    }
    if (lng == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(lng);
    }
    if (name == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(name);
    }
    if (type_2 == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(type_2);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static final Parcelable.Creator<MarkerList> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MarkerList>() {
    @Override
    public MarkerList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MarkerList(in);
    }

    @Override
    public MarkerList[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MarkerList[size];
    }
};
}
```

Comment: О круто. Спс...

Comment: Это дополнение к ответу Юрия, наличие подобных сайтов-помощников не означает, что их нужно бездумно применять :)